# creation of afwin file in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I was finding an error when building. It avers that there were some undeclared variables. When I went to see their origins from some other projects, it seems that they are linked to a certain afwin.h.

I m talking about some variables / classes / identifies which are:

- CDialog
- LPCSTR
- CWnd

When trying to include afwin.h into my project, the build still doesn't recognize them.

Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 2):

This refers to the MFC (Microsoft Foundation Classes), which is an OO-Framework and is a set above the Win32-API. If you use Visual Studio Express you won't be able to use it.

See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library).

Comment: Thank you.
Actually, I m using Visual Studio 2010.
According to you, how can I add that to my project for that it recognizes those declarations?

Comment: Depends on the fact, whether you have Visual Studio 2010 Express or any other (usually expensive) version. Under C++/Win32 you can create a new MFC-project and then add your contents. Maybe this works.